# How to disable dates before tomorrow in jquery UI datepicker

Tags: php, jquery

I want to disable dates before t+omorrow but dont work with min and max.

```
view:

   <input id="date_modified" type="text" class="form-control" value="">
```

jquery:

```
 $('#date_modified').persianDatepicker({
        observer: true,
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
        min: 0,
        maxDate: new Date(),
            onSelect: function () {
                var value = $('#date_modified').val();
                checkVisiTHour(value);

            }


    }).pDatepicker('setDate', [today+1]);


});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQueryUI [Datepicker page](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max):

> Restrict the range of selectable dates with the minDate and maxDate
>   options. Set the beginning and end dates as actual dates (new
>   Date(2009, 1 - 1, 26)), as a numeric offset from today (-20), or as a
>   string of periods and units ('+1M +10D'). For the last, use 'D' for
>   days, 'W' for weeks, 'M' for months, or 'Y' for years.

As such, you should be able to do :

```
$( function() {
    $( "#date_modified" ).datepicker({ minDate: +1});
});
```

and add in any other attributes you need

Comment: @F.Joodaki are there any errors in the javascript developer console?

Comment: no, its work for disable dates before today but not work for disable dates before tomorrow

Comment: Have you tried +2 instead of +1, just in case it's doing an odd calculation on the date?